# ETH transaction is always pending and I can't replace it

Tags: blockchain

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdeb5275a3008d89831c6767890f27137a227214b3a76bff5c9e4e0f043439f94

I used the same nonce and used higher gas but was told the transaction failed，I clicked cancel or speed up and still no feedback[image]

Comment: It had a very low gas price of 2gwei, around that time most transactions had above 55gwei. You can try checking some gas tracker before submitting a transaction. For example https://etherscan.io/gastracker.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what causes this pending your txs.
However, in my experience, you can handle it in the following ways:

1. Increase **gas limit** (as you did) and increase **priority fee**.
2. Swap to another stablecoin such as USDC or DAI to transfer quickly with reasonable gas fees.